# Bootstrap show svg and text in row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to show button with svg image and text in row.

I am doing it like this

```
    <button class='btn btn-primary' style='background-color:purple; display: flex;'>
        <div style='text-align:center;'>
            <img src="assets/icons/Icon awesome-crown.svg" class="img-fluid" width="20px" height="20px">
        </div>
        Top Pick
    </button>
```

Its showing like this

[image]

I need to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `align-items:center` along with display:flex. Also, give a `margin-right` to the icon.

```
   <button class='btn btn-primary' style='background-color:purple; display: flex;align-items:center;'>
            <div style='text-align:center;'>
                <img src="https://vaibhavvijay.me/images/envelope-white.svg" class="img-fluid" style='margin-right:8px;' width="20px" height="20px">
            </div>
            Top Pick
    </button>
```

Comment: Thanks but still having issue with image and text not in centre horizontally. tried with text-align in button also

Comment: align-items:center should work. If still issue, please share the code on Codepen, JSfiddle etc.